# Setting rules doesn't work in jQuery Validate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use the jQuery Validation Plugin (jqueryvalidation.org), but it doesn't work.
http://jsfiddle.net/k8GnD/1/
I want to set the rules for the inputs in an external script and not inline, as the documentation suggests.
You should only be able to click the send-button when "name", "email" and "text" aren't empty and "website" doesn't contain something else then an url.

```
$(function() {
    $("#gb_form").validate({
        rules: {
            name: 'required',
            'email': {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            '#website': {
                url: true
            },
            text: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function() {
            console.log('Clicked');
            alert('Clicked');
//            ...
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see I tried some different things, but the only things which get validated are website and email and they propably, because I used type="..." there. :(

Comment: Start with the basics:  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML, as it is right now, needs to set the *name* of the fields, not just the id.

```
<form id="gb_form" action="/" method="post">
    <div class="gb_input_box">
        <label for="name">Name *</label> 
        <input name="name" id="name" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="gb_input_box">
        <label for="email">E-Mail *<br /></label>
        <input name="email" id="email" type="email" /></div>
    <div class="gb_input_box">
        <label for="website">Website</label> 
        <input name="website" id="website" type="url" />
    </div>
    <div class="gb_input_box">
        <label for="text">Text</label>
        <textarea name="text" id="text"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

`validate()` binds to the `name` of the field.

```
<input name="name" type="text" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k8GnD/2/